# In C# is it possible to add a value to a collection while at the same time assigning it to another variable

Tags: c#

I am using the conditional operator to check if a value is already cached in a collection and if it is not, call the appropriate method as follows:

```
facilityQuantity = facilityFundedAmts.ContainsKey(facilityId) ? facilityFundedAmts[facilityId] : facilityHolding.Funded();
```

Is it possible somehow to add the `facilityHolding.Funded()` to my `facilityFundedAmts` collection in the same line?

Comment: Is this a multi-thread application?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about an extension method to encapsulate what you're doing?  You can pass it the key and a function that can be used to create the value if it doesn't exist:

```
public static TValue GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source, TKey key, Func<TValue> valueFunc)
{
    TValue value;

    if (!source.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
        value = valueFunc();
        source.Add(key, value);
    }

    return value;
}
```

And use it as below:

```
facilityQuantity = facilityFundedAmts.GetOrAdd(facilityId, () => facilityHolding.Funded());
```

As pointed out in the comments, there is an implicit conversion available from method group to `Func<TValue>`, so you could also write this as:

```
facilityQuantity = facilityFundedAmts.GetOrAdd(facilityId, facilityHolding.Funded);
```

Comment: In this particular case, `() => facilityHolding.Funded()` can be probably written as `facilityHolding.Funded`

Comment: @xanatos good point, that should work.  I'll add it in as an option.

Comment: The ConcurrentDictionary class also has this built in. Same name, same signature.

Comment: @neilh my inspiration!  I'd use a `Dictionary` unless I required the concurrency though, there is usually quite a performance hit in using the concurrent collections.

Comment: @CharlesMager thanks a lot. This is something new I learned today. I  implemented this and the code looks elegant and concise.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as a single statement, but that involves misusing the conditional operator as an `if ... else` statement/expression:

```
facilityFundedAmts.ContainsKey(facilityId) ? facilityQuantity = facilityFundedAmts[facilityId] : facilityFundedAmts.Add(facilityQuantity = facilityHolding.Funded());
```

You can use `TryGetValue` to access the item only once if it exists, and add it if it doesn't exist:

```
if (!facilityFundedAmts.TryGetValue(facilityId, out facilityQuantity)) {
  facilityFundedAmts.Add(facilityQuantity = facilityHolding.Funded());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible somehow to add the facilityHolding.Funded() to my facilityFundedAmts collection in the same line?

Sure:

```
facilityQuantity = facilityFundedAmts.ContainsKey(facilityId) ? facilityFundedAmts[facilityId] : facilityFundedAmts[facilityId] = facilityHolding.Funded();
```

Assigning to an indexed property like `facilityFundedAmts[]` is treated like an expression, so that then assigning it to something applies the getter.

If the getter was expensive, (I'm assuming you are using `Dictionary` in which the getter is not expensive, but still...) then this would be too, which means that:

```
if(facilityFundedAmts.ContainsKey(facilityId))
  facilityQuantity = facilityFundedAmts[facilityId]
else
  facilityFundedAmts[facilityId] = facilityQuantity = facilityHolding.Funded();
```

Is marginally more efficient. It's not really worth bothering with (it's **really** marginal with any half-decent collection) except that it stands as an example of how one-line in the source code does not necessarily mean most efficent in the produced code.

Now, that said.

```
if(!facilityFundedAmts.TryGetValue(facilityId, out facilityQuantity)) facilityFundedAmts.Add(facilityId, facilityQuantity = facilityHolding.Funded());
```

In fact beats both on both counts. Personally I'd consider putting it on one line to be poor style though.

Comment: thanks a lot for the insight. After being out of dev for over 7 years, just getting my hands dirty again. Your comments are very useful.